# Google Colab - AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'seek' and 'read'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to concatenate 3 images horizontaly. I've found a way that seems good enough on the the internet, the problem is that I'm having two errors that I can't figure out how to fix.

Note: I'm using Google Colab with Python 3.

Here is the errors:

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'seek'`

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'`

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys
import PIL
import cv2

rgb = cv2.imread("/content/teste/LC08_L1TP_222063_20180702_20180716_01_T1_1_3.tif")
tir = cv2.imread("/content/teste/LC08_L1TP_222063_20180702_20180716_01_T1_TIR_1_3.tif")
qb = cv2.imread("/content/teste/LC08_L1TP_222063_20180702_20180716_01_T1_QB_1_3.tif")


list_im = [rgb, tir, qb]
imgs    = [ PIL.Image.open(i) for i in list_im ]
# pick the image which is the smallest, and resize the others to match it (can be arbitrary image shape here)
min_shape = sorted( [(np.sum(i.size), i.size ) for i in imgs])[0][1]
imgs_comb = np.hstack( (np.asarray( i.resize(min_shape) ) for i in imgs ) )

# save that beautiful picture
imgs_comb = PIL.Image.fromarray( imgs_comb)
imgs_comb.save( 'Trifecta.jpg' )
```

Apparently the error happens on this line: `---> 12| imgs    = [ PIL.Image.open(i) for i in list_im ]`

And because of it I tried to update the `Pillow` library to 5.3.0, but the error still happens, what should I do?

Comment: Each of `rgb`, `tir`, and `qb` are numpy arrays (that's what `imread()` returns). But you're trying to use PIL to "open" these numpy arrays. Instead you want PIL to open the files. So pass PIL the filenames instead of the arrays, or just don't use PIL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about not using pil, seems like opencv can do want you want

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys
import cv2

rgb = cv2.imread("/content/teste/LC08_L1TP_222063_20180702_20180716_01_T1_1_3.tif")
tir = cv2.imread("/content/teste/LC08_L1TP_222063_20180702_20180716_01_T1_TIR_1_3.tif")
qb = cv2.imread("/content/teste/LC08_L1TP_222063_20180702_20180716_01_T1_QB_1_3.tif")

list_im = [rgb, tir, qb]

# pick the image which is the smallest, and resize the others to match it (can be arbitrary image shape here)
min_width = min([img.shape[1] for img in list_im])
min_height = min([img.shape[0] for img in list_im])
list_img = [cv2.resize(img, (min_width, min_height)) for img in list_im]

imgs_comb = np.hstack( list_img )

# save that beautiful picture
cv2.imwrite('result.jpg', imgs_comb)
```